# Select all rows except one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use a select statement to get all the rows from a certain MySQL table except for one which will be incremented by its previous value
e.g.

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | google |
| 2  | yahoo  |
| 3  | msn    |
| 4  | google |
| 5  | google |
| 6  | yahoo  |
+----+--------+
```

Now, every time i add a new value it will be 7,8,9.. now i want to select the row except the new value inserted in table

Comment: So you want all rows except the one with the highest id?

Comment: If it's just a case of excluding the last row returned in a data set, it might be simpler to do that in the application logic.

Comment: `... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 999999999999999999 OFFSET 1` :-)

Answer (score 4):

Write a subquery that gets the highest `id`, then exclude that with a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a subquery that get the max id 
Then get all id's smaller than the max id in the `WHERE`.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
  [table]
WHERE
 id < (
   SELECT 
     MAX(id) 
   FROM 
     [table]
 )
```